# How do I loop through an array when sending an email with the mail gem in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, email, gmail

I'm trying to loop through an array *in the body of an email* using the gmail gem (which, as I understand it, uses the mail gem for sending mail).

How do I loop through an array in the body of an email using the mail gem? Seems so simple, and yet, I can't get it going.

The method below doesn't work, but shows what I'd like to do.

```
def deliver_mail(gmail, email, result, request_type)
  client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :database => 'bigmake_development')
  investments = client.query("SELECT * FROM investments WHERE investor_id = '#{result[:id]}'")

  gmail.deliver do
    to email.from_addrs
    subject "My Subject!"

    body do
      investments.each do |i|
        i['target']
        i['deal_type']
        i['round']
        i['deal_date']
      end
    end  
  end
  puts "Email reply sent to #{email.from_addrs}"
end
```

Working examples that I've seen are usually formatted like this:

```
def deliver_mail(gmail, email, result, request_type)
  gmail.deliver do
    to email.from_addrs
    subject "My Subject!"
    body "Hello!"
    # or like this
    body File.load('body.txt')
  end
end
```

However, I don't think either of those methods will work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you just trying to build a string? Something like this should work:

```
  body_content = ""
  investments.each do |i|
    body_content += "#{i['target']} #{i['deal_type']} #{i['round']} #{i['deal_date']}\n"
  end
  gmail.deliver do
    to email.from_addrs
    subject "My Subject!"
    body body_content
  end
```

If you wanted to get more complex, I would look into something like [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html).